# Ошибка при запуске CRON

Tags: php, cron

При запуске cron выдает ошибку:

> root# /usr/bin/php /var/www/www-root/data/************/email.php
>   PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: count_email_send in /var/www/www-root/data/***********/mod_email.php on line 131

### Фрагмент кода:

```html
function go_email ($number_email,$subject,$message,$limit,$db)
{
 $db;
 $message = email_message($message); 
 
 $all_email = mysql_query("SELECT email, email_md5_key FROM mak_email WHERE dispatch < $number_email && blocking = 0 && unsubscribe = 0 $limit");
  while($email = mysql_fetch_array($all_email)):
   
   $message_url = massage_url($message, $email[1], $number_email);
 
   mak_email($email[0],$subject,$message_url);
   
   mysql_query ("UPDATE mak_email set dispatch = '".$number_email."' WHERE email = '".$email[0]."'");
 
   $count_email_send++; #131 строка по которой пишет лажу
   
  endwhile;
 
 return $count_email_send;
}
```

---

Ничего не трогал, до этого все работало на ура. Помогите, в какую сторону копать?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: `Ничего не трогал` - так не бывает. Наверняка что-то да делали. Например обновляли PHP. В целом это предупреждение не должно сказываться на работе скрипта - оно просто предупреждает, что "ай-ай-ай, не хорошо!", но работать продолжает

Comment: `$db;`? Чо это? Просто чтобы было?

Answer (score 2):

В данной функции не определена переменная `$count_email_send`, которая инкрементируется.
Возможный вариант решения: добавить в начале функции определение переменной `$count_email_send = 0;`